# Dynamically setting the IDMultilingual value by using select

Tags: sql

In my `INNER JOIN` clause, I want to set the column `IDMultilingual` value dynamically by using a select statement. Must I use the `IN` clause, and may I use `EXISTS` clause?

```
INNER JOIN  MLTA ON MLTA.IDObject = MSR.idobject 
        AND MLTA.IDObjectType = 15
        AND MLTA.IDMultilingual = SELECT ID 
                                  FROM   MLA 
                                  WHERE  Columnname = 'SHOW' 
                                  AND    Tablename = 'Category'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add an extra `JOIN` to the same table `MLTA` with a new alias. Something like:

```
...
INNER JOIN MLTA   m  ON m.IDObject       = MSR.idobject 
                    AND m.IDObjectType   = 15
INNER JOIN MLTA  m2  ON m.IDMultilingual = m2.ID     ---<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<
....
```

However, you can use the `IN` predicate like this:

```
....
INNER JOIN  MLTA ON MLTA.IDObject = MSR.idobject 
        AND MLTA.IDObjectType = 15
WHERE MLTA.IDMultilingual IN(SELECT ID 
                             from MLA 
                             WHERE Columnname = 'SHOW' 
                               AND Tablename = 'Category');
```

or the `EXISTS` predicate the same way, and it might be safer than the `IN` predicate in case of the `NULL` values of the column `ID`.